# Finding stylus for desktop touch LCD

Tags: touchscreen

I recently bought an Acer [T232HL](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.VT2AA.001) LCD touchscreen monitor. How do you find a stylus that works with this touchscreen, or do you have some examples of ones that do?

I have Windows 7 and the touchscreen works out of the box without installing any additional software. Windows auto-installed the driver with PnP. So far, the touchscreen seems to only work with fingers.

Comment: When I did a google search for "stylus for T232HL bmidz" from the link you provided, I found this page http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Acer-T232HL-bmidz-23-Inch-Touchscreen-Display/productID.258713500 which details a capacitive brush and stylus you can purchase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the touchscreen sensor on the monitor is capacitive, any old capacitive stylus will work. A "Works with iPad" on the box is a dead giveaway, but in general look for a (usually black) rubber dome on the end of the stylus.